# getElementsByTagName doesn't work for my <a> tags

Tags: javascript, dom

I can't get this to work:

```
    <p>
        <a href="#">First</a>
        <a href="#" id="hasID">Second</a>
        <a href="#">Third</a>
        <a href="#" id="someID">Fourth</a>
    </p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

    <script>
        var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        link.style.fontSize = '16px';
        link.style.textDecoration = 'none';
        link.style.color = '#333333';
        link.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    </script>
```

I'm trying to add CSS styles (`font-size`, `text-decoration`, `color`, `font-weight`) to all the `<a>` tags of my HTML code.

Comment: When are you executing this script ? Before the anchor markup ?

Comment: Does your script come before the links on the page?

Comment: @DidierGhys - Tried it on [link](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Finally got the JS working. @JaredPar is correct. _You need to loop through the links and apply the changes to the individual items._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't working because you're trying to apply the changes to the list vs. the individual links.  You need to loop through the links and apply the changes to the individual items

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  var link = all[i];
  link.style.fontSize = '16px';
  link.style.textDecoration = 'none';
  link.style.color = '#333333';
  link.style.fontWeight = 'bold'
}
```

Additionally it looks like your script is running before the `a` elements are defined.  Hence the `getElementsByTagName` will return an empty collection.  Try moving the script to after the definition of the anchor elements

Answer (score 1):

When the closing tag of that `<script>` block is encountered, the whole code in it is evaluated. Since anything after `</script>` has not been parsed yet, the result from `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` is not as expected.

Wrap the method in an `onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` event.

It seems that you want to target **all** anchor elements. Instead of looping through all anchorts, you'd better append a `<style>` element with the given CSS text:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // `window.attachEvent('onload', function() {` for old IE versions
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    var cssText = 'a,a:link,a:visited {' +
             'font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#333;font-weight:bold;}';
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssText));
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}, false);
```

Comment: PS. For IE, you have to use `style.styleSheet.cssText = cssText;` instead of `.appendChild(...)`.

Comment: Or you could just use a css file, and not use JS at all :-P